# How to check a particular column references parent table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a child table say `B` which references to some parent table say `A`. Now, suppose i have 3 coulmns in table B (example: `B1, B2,B3`). I wrote a query to get all the constraints in table B which is as follows:

```
SELECT a.table_name, 
       a.column_name
FROM ALL_CONS_COLUMNS A, ALL_CONSTRAINTS C  
where A.CONSTRAINT_NAME = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
  and a.table_name='B'
  and C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'C'
```

Result:

```
Table Name Column Name
B          B1
```

Now i want to know that column `B1` references to which **parent table** along with the **column name** too.

Answer (score 0):

I just happened to have this query lying around:

```
SELECT
FK_Table = FK.TABLE_NAME,
FK_Column = CU.COLUMN_NAME,
PK_Table = PK.TABLE_NAME,
Constraint_Name = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN (
SELECT i1.TABLE_NAME, i2.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i1
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE i2 ON i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = i2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE i1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
) PT ON PT.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME
---- optional:
ORDER BY
1,2,3,4
```

It should do what you want.

Comment: Edited to get rid of extraneous columns

Comment: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: OK. That SQL is for SQL Server and definitely won't work in Oracle! And you did put an Oracle tag on it, so apologies for wasting your time...

Comment: Have look at http://anuj-singh.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/oracle-primary-key-foreign-key-report.html

Answer (score 0):

Try following sqls:

Get all child tables and columns by parent,

```
SELECT distinct confk.constraint_name,
  confk.constraint_type,
  confk.table_name child_table,
  fkcon.column_name child_column,
  conpk.table_name parent_table,
  pkcon.column_name parent_column
FROM dba_constraints confk,
  dba_constraints conpk,
  dba_cons_columns pkcon,
  dba_cons_columns fkcon
WHERE confk.r_constraint_name = conpk.constraint_name
AND conpk.constraint_name     = pkcon.constraint_name
AND confk.constraint_name     = fkcon.constraint_name
AND confk.constraint_type     = 'R'
AND pkcon.owner               = 'Your schema name'
AND pkcon.table_name          ='your parent table name'
AND pkcon.column_name         ='your parent column name';
```

Get the parent table name and column by child name and column,

```
SELECT distinct confk.constraint_name,
  confk.constraint_type,
  confk.table_name child_table,
  fkcon.column_name child_column,
  conpk.table_name parent_table,
  pkcon.column_name parent_column
FROM dba_constraints confk,
  dba_constraints conpk,
  dba_cons_columns pkcon,
  dba_cons_columns fkcon
WHERE confk.r_constraint_name = conpk.constraint_name
AND conpk.constraint_name     = pkcon.constraint_name
AND confk.constraint_name     = fkcon.constraint_name
AND confk.constraint_type     = 'R'
AND fkcon.owner               = 'Your schema name'
AND fkcon.table_name          ='your child table name'
AND fkcon.column_name         ='your child column name';
```